# How do I display an error in my bash script, If user enters no value

Tags: linux, bash, error-handling, terminal

```
echo " Enter the number of rows :- "
read rows

echo " Enter the special symbol :- "
read sym



for row in $(seq 1 $rows)
do
        for col in $(seq 1 $row)
        do
            sym=$((sym+1))
           
            echo -n " $sym "
        done
        echo
done
```

I wanted to display an error if user does not any value for rows and symbol.
I still can not figure it out.

Comment: Hello Tarandeep, welcome to SO. Its good that you have shown your efforts in form of code, keep it up. Adding what you are trying to achieve in your question is important too. So kindly do add what you are trying to achieve in words and what's not working in details(in your question not in comments please), so that we will get a better picture of your question, thank you.

Comment: `if [[ -z $rows || -z $sym ]]`?